# qlikview set expression with chr()-function

Tags: function, qlikview, dollar-sign

I am Setting some variables in the script of my qlikview application. Later on I try to reuse one of the previous variables but qlikview is giving me an error.

`SET vCurrentMonth = "=CAL.MONTH";`
`SET vMonthCounter = "SUM({<MONTH = {'$(vCurrentMonth)'}>} Counter)";`
I was trying to use the $-expansion as already known from the normal set expressions that are not in the Script. But then I did not receive any data.
After some Research I found that I must replace the $ with the chr()-function.
`SET vMonthCounter = "SUM({<MONTH = {'" & chr(36)& "(vCurrentMonth)'}>} Counter)";`
But this chr()-function is returning a string so I don't receive the sum of my Counter but the string of the set Expression ($03).
What am I doing wrong? Can anybody explain how to use this function in the script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me even without using the `chr()` function. I've added `=` before the `sum` (i've used simple string for `vCurrentMonth` and remove the `=` there):

`SET vMonthCounter = "=SUM({<MONTH = {'$(vCurrentMonth)'}>} Counter)";`

and then using the variable in text box (like below) is giving me the correct result:

`= vMonthCounter`

If you still prefer the `chr()` approach then some changes in the `vMonthCounter` are needed to get the same result:

`let vMonthCounter1 = '=SUM({ <category = {' & chr(39) & chr(36) & '(vCurrentMonth)' & chr(39) & '} >} value)';`

- `set` is replaced with `let`. `let` evaluates the expression and will actually run and replace the `chr()` with the symbols (btw when using `set` you are not obligated to enclose the string in any quotes)
- replaced the start and end quotes with single quote
- the single quotes inside the set expressions are replaced with `chr(39)`

Comment: Hi Stefan the first attempt you mentioned is not working for me but the second one is working fine. Do you know if I can use this variable in an if-function that will appear later in the script?

Comment: you can't run set analysis in the script. This variable will only make sense in the UI.

Comment: okay no I got a running solution thanks a lot for your support